# Need to extract URLs from a CSV file - GREP OR FINDSTR ONLY

Tags: bash, csv, grep, findstr

I'm looking for a one line GREP or FINDSTR script that will scan a folder full of 4 column CSV files and extract only URLS and output them into a text file, one URL on each line. The URLs are in the format "http://example.com/" I've been playing with this script but I can't seem to get it to output anything

```
cat filename | grep http | grep -shoP 'http.*?[" >]' > outfilename
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this one:

```
find BASEDIR -type f -exec grep -oP "\bhttp://[^/]*/" {} \; > OUTFILE
```

It's not needed that the files under BASEDIR are CSV files.

**Edit**

If you want the full URL (not in the format 'http://example.com/' but 'http://example.com/path') and assuming the CSV separator is ';', then

```
find BASEDIR -type f -exec grep -oP "\bhttp://[^;]*" {} \; > OUTFILE
```

Comment: The regular expression only extract domains instead of the full URL, asked.